# Is there any reason why API paths should use plural nouns as apposed to singular?

Tags: api, http, url, naming-conventions

Just curious, but I am making an API and have been thus far using URLs like this:

/user/create

/user/[id]

and now I am adding

/user/create/batch

This made me wonder if there is any good reason I should call the user management endpoint 'users' rather than just 'user'. Then again, maybe it doesn't matter at all. I would at least guess I should be consistent about this either way.

Thoughts?

Comment: Close for 'off topic'? In which SE should a question about designing an API be other than one about software development?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RESTful POSTS, do you POST objects to the singular or plural Uri?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690267/restful-posts-do-you-post-objects-to-the-singular-or-plural-uri)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I nearly always use plurals in my url design. I always think of navigating in my url paths, similar to directories, where I am descending deeper and deeper.

There is a top resource (like `/users`) which expresses a collection and there are sub-resources (like `/users/{userId}/items`) which itself is a collection.

All apis and their representing domain I have seen so far would have fit to above recommendation.

Regarding your mentioned `/users/create/batch` looks like you want to encode an 'action' inside url. In a restful design over HTTP it would fit better if you use HTTP methods `POST /users` (single user payload) or for batch creation mode transmitting multiple users. 
What does the 'create' and 'batch' mean in your case?

Comment: About the last part, I was differentiating the URL based on whether you were sending one XML user or a group of many XML users. The reason I made the URLs different? Because it seemed easier as ASP.NET MVC doesn't seem to consider the parameter list as part of the Action so when I make the same Action (/users/create/) accept two different variables (user or list) it won't know how to decide which one to use... I guess it's lazy of me but I don't know how else I would figure it out unless I did some crazy custom model binding.

Answer (score -1):

I would say that you should use 'user' for activities relating to a known specific user, and 'users' for activities related to all users (like, say, global cleanup operations), modifying the user pool (like your `create`) or for obtaining that reference to a known specific user.

I would have `/users/select` or `/users/search` to find/get a user, or `/users/cleanup` to do something to all users.

I would have `/user/[id]/operation` to do something to/with a specific user.

There is an argument that, as you say, it doesn't matter at all...

Comment: The only gripe I have with not doing it the same every time is when I think about the various developers who will be using the API in their code, I don't want to create one of those annoying "crap I forgot to add an s to the URL" moments while they are coding. I'd rather just have it be clear and straight forward off the cuff.

Comment: @Ryan That's fair enough - it's really a judgement call, based on how much you think you need to spoon-feed your users. In that case I would probably go with `users` over `user`, simply because you have more than one of them.

Comment: /users/search is a clunky structure, since GET /users should enable searching based on a parameter or filter i.e. GET /users?email={email}