# Should you use plural or singular form of folder name in URL

Tags: web-services, api, http, url, rest

Example 1:

```
http://www.example.com/image/logo.png
http://www.example.com/images/logo.png
```

Example 2:

```
http://www.example.com/user/johndoe
http://www.example.com/users/johndoe
```

Especially if you use the Url as REST API. (Example 2)

Which one is recommended and why?

Comment: Grammatically, I prefer the plural: The folder is going to contain *multiple* of those things. I don't understand how there could ever be a *technical* reason to prefer one or the other options, though, so this question might be better asked on a site like http://english.stackexchange.com/ or http://ux.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: One way to think about it is a folder is unlikely to contain only a single image so it makes sense that the folder should be pluralized.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RESTful POSTS, do you POST objects to the singular or plural Uri?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690267/restful-posts-do-you-post-objects-to-the-singular-or-plural-uri)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For REST, i mainly use the plural form to indicate a path to the resource. But you also have to take the Cacheablility, Frequency of Change and the Mutability of the Resource. In my case, collections of the resource is mainly the case, so i had used the plural form.

The reason for this is that for example:

```
http://www.example.com/users/johndoe
```

will serve the URI to GET the user johndoe which belongs to your collection of users.

```
http://www.example.com/users
```

will be used as the URI to GET all users and can be easily be used on query url like:

```
http://www.example.com/users?limit=5
```

creating a new user will still use the same URL then using POST & passing the parameters:

```
http://www.example.com/users
```

for refs you may want to check the Oreilly book RESTful Web Services Cookbook

Answer (score 1):

My personal preference would be to use different url for single and multiple resources.

http://www.example.com/users say that I want all the uses. You can append query parameters to filter the results though.

On contrarily
 http://www.example.com/user/johndoe -  explicitly states that I want a single user whose id is johndoe.

Advantages:
1. Expectation cant be set correctly.
2. /users with no results can be return 201 instead of 404
3. /user/ can return 401 which is error condition.